# How to survey recommended course readings?

Tags: citations, data

I am interested in analysing the selection and distribution of course readings given to students of middle eastern studies in universities internationally.

By course readings I am referring to subject bibliographies given to students as background reading to accompany lectures, etc. I suspect this would be difficult to investigate, since most course readers are not available online.

Does anyone know of lists, bibliographies, methods or other resources which may help to conduct such a survey of course readings?

Comment: Isn't this an xy question ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )? If you want to find bibliographies for a specific topic, why not directly ask that question?

Comment: Thanks Silvado, I completely agree. I have rephrased my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a tricky task, as you are quite correct, many universities won't necessarily publish online and there are scant compilations for course readings specifically.

However, having said that, I found this [Middle Eastern Teaching tools link list](http://www.middleeastpdx.org/resources/other-resources/) from the University of Portland and [this compilation by a Dr. Alan Godlas](http://islam.uga.edu/MESCenters.html).

At the bottom of the 2nd link is information regarding listserv's which may be of help.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I did come across Dr. Alan Godias' lists but thought my question might be a bit off topic.

Comment: No problems, another idea came to mind and that is to try and develop such a compilation yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to do. Do you know anyone that would be interested to collaborate on this?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest (I am in a totally different field). Perhaps contact some fellow academics for a collaborative project.